# Custom listview with youtube video in android

Tags: android, youtube

I am trying to create a Youtube video Listview, It works statically by giving specific URL, but i want to do it dynamically using JSON.

This is my code:

```
public class ActivityVideos extends DrawerActivity{

private static final String TAG = ActivityVideos.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String url = Util.VIDEO_URL;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<VideoModel> videoList = new ArrayList<VideoModel>();
//private ListView listView;
RecyclerView listView;
//private VideoAdapter adapter;
RecyclerAdapter adapter;
//private String bitmap = "thumbnailUrl";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_videos);


    listView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //to use RecycleView, you need a layout manager. default is LinearLayoutManager
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    listView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(ActivityVideos.this,videoList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest videoReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            VideoModel msg = new VideoModel();

                            msg.setVideoUrl(Util.VIDEO_URL+obj.getString("img"));

                            videoList.add(msg);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(videoReq);
    //gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    /*listView.setLongClickable(true);
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);*/
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
```

This is my Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

//these ids are the unique id for each video
//String[] videoItems = {"P3mAtvs5Elc", "nCgQDjiotG0", "P3mAtvs5Elc"};
Context ctx;
private Activity activity;
private List<VideoModel> videoItems;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<VideoModel> videoItems)
{
    this.ctx = context;
    this.videoItems = videoItems;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_recycler_adapter, parent, false);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_recycler_adapter, null);

    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;

    //return new VideoInfoHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener  onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
            youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo((videoItems.get(position));
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            //write something for failure
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return videoItems.size();
}

/*public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
    protected ImageView playButton;

    public VideoInfoHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        playButton=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
        youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, videoItems[getLayoutPosition()],100,true,false);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}*/

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
    protected ImageView playButton;
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        playButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
        youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView)view.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, videoItems,100,true,false);

        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

I am getting a problem at:

`youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo((videoItems.get(position));`

and

`Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity)ctx, Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, videoItems, 100, true, false);`

The problem, is that I am not getting videoItems in both, String parameter is needed there but I have a list.

Is there any solution.?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is send a Listener like a parameter in your Adapter constructor to control the taps.

In your solution you can do the following at `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
holder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, videoItems.get(position).getURL(),100,true,false);

            ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, is just `videoItems.get(position)`. I will update it.

Comment: @mansimervana `videoItems.get(position)` retrieve a VIdeoModel object. Call the property related to the URL. **Example** `videoItems.get(position).getUrl()`,

Comment: Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, videoItems,100,true,false);

Comment: i tried..its not working..videoItems.get(position).getUrl()

Comment: did anyone find solution...?

Comment: Update your question and share the code for VideoModel class.